# how can I get a some values in strings in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, telnet

hi I looked the others questions and tried some things but i couldnt manage to solve it.

My string is that

```
:CONNECTING TO CPL... PROCESS CPL CONNECTED... Enter command: Enter
command:RESP:0,CPrL-E1002:RESPMSG,Invalid session ID.; Enter
command:RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error; Enter command:
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

how Can I take `RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error;` this line? Also
RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error; this line wıll change according the request .So I must take only from RESP: to ; for the second line

Comment: `tried some things` -- can you elaborate?  Tried what?

Comment: for example grep "command:RESP:0,CNDB-0,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success;" $allres | while read line 
do 
    echo $line;   
done
it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. test=":CONNECTING TO CPL... PROCESS CPL CONNECTED... Enter command: Enter command:RESP:0,CPrL-E1002:RESPMSG,Invalid session ID.; Enter command:RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error; Enter command:Connection closed by foreign host."
2. str=`echo $test | cut -d";" -f2`
3. echo ${str:15:100}";"

Here I assumed that your response string comes every time after " Enter command:". 100 is for the maximum length of your response string.

Comment: I tried this:str=$(echo $allres | cut -d";" -f2) echo $str output:       Enter command: Enter command:RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success; and so How can take from this line RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success ? so thanks

Comment: sorry use this str=\`echo $test | cut -d";" -f2\`.
I wrote \' first time also but it did not appear in post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string is in a variable named `$str`, and that there are no other stars `*` in the string, you could use an awk filter, like this:

```
awk -F\* 'NF>1{print $2}' <<< "$str"
```

Here we use the `-F` option to set the field separator to the star, and if we find a line with more than one elements (one star or more), we print the second field.

output:

```
$ echo "$str"
:CONNECTING TO CPL... PROCESS CPL CONNECTED... Enter command: Enter
command:*RESP:0,CPrL-E1002:RESPMSG,Invalid session ID.;* Enter
command:AREE:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error; Enter command:
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
$ awk -F\* 'NF>1{print $2}' <<< "$str"
RESP:0,CPrL-E1002:RESPMSG,Invalid session ID.;
```

Comment: I coded like this :a=$(awk -F\* 'NF>1{print $2}' <<< "$allres")
echo $a
but I didnt see any result @user000001

Comment: @hccccc By what criteria do you select the substring? E.g Is it always  the 3rd line you want?

Comment: Actually,in my pc there are two lines.

Comment: first line:CONNECTING TO CPL... PROCESS CPL CONNECTED... Enter command:RESP:0,CNDB-0,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success; Enter command: Enter command

Comment: and second one :RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success; Enter command: Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: @hccccc It is better to edit your question to make the string *exactly* like the one you have. Add four spaces in front so it is formatted as code. Still though, what are the criteria for selecting the substring to keep?

Comment: Actually I dont know itis always coming in second line.-:RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success;-.

Comment: So basically you want to keep the second line of the string?

Comment: yes second line and this string -RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success;

Comment: Try `awk 'NR==2' <<< "$str"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use expr and regular expressions, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033005/824495) answer first. Have a look at this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
# foo.sh

# Searches the string for a "RESP:#" message, the # sign is a digit.

string='CONNECTING TO CPL... PROCESS CPL CONNECTED... Enter command:RESP:0,CNDB-0,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success; Enter command: Enter command:
RESP:1,CPL-0,EMA-0:RESPMSG,success; Enter command: Connection closed by foreign host'
regex='RESP\:[0-9]\,CPL\-0\,EMA\-0\:RESPMSG\,[a-zA-Z0-9]*\;'

line=`expr "$string" : '.*\(RESP\:[0-9]\,CPL\-0\,EMA\-0\:RESPMSG\,[a-zA-Z0-9]*\;\)'` # Search the string for the desired line.
respCode=${line:5:1} # Extract RESP:# value using substring...
respMessage=${line:27}
echo $line
echo 'Received response code : '$respCode
echo 'Received response message : '$respMessage
```

Comment: date
for i in {3..5}
 do 

 CMDCount="CMD"$i
 eval CMD="$"$CMDCount 
 echo "CMD "${CMD}""; 
 echo "" 

 allres=$((sleep 1;echo $login; 
 sleep 1;
 echo ${CMD}; 
 sleep 1;
 echo $logout;sleep 1)|telnet localhost 9685) 
 sleep 1;

str=$(echo $allres | cut -d";" -f2)
echo 'Response :'  ${str:30:1000}";"
if [ "${str:30:100}" == "$resp" ]; then
    echo 'Status: PASS'
else
    echo 'Status: FAIL'
fi
echo "-------";
done

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this using only [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ grep -oP 'command:\KRESP:.*?System internal error;' test.txt
RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error;
```

Comment: ,Actually,RESP:0,CPL-E1014:RESPMSG,System internal error; this line wıll change according the request .So I must take only  from RESP: to ;  for the second line.ok?